# One to Many relationship cascade delete hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm starting with hibernate, I have a one to many relationship between 2 athlete-medals classes and I was wondering if it was possible to **delete** an **athlete** and cascade eliminate all the medals associated with it?

here are the he classes that intervene

---

### athletes

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Deportistas")
    public class Deportistas implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "codDeportista")
        private int coddeportista;

        @Column(name = "nombreDeportista", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(60)")
        private String nombredeportista;

        @Column(name = "dniDeportista", columnDefinition="CHAR(12)")
        private String dnideportista;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "paisDeportista")
        private Paises pais;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="coddeportista", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Medallas> medalladeportista;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="iddeportista", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Licencias licenciadeportista;

        public Deportistas() {

        }


----------
## medals ##

@Entity
@Table(name = "Medallas")
public class Medallas implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codDeportista")
    private Deportistas coddeportista;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codPrueba")
    private Pruebas codprueba;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fechaMedalla", columnDefinition="DATE")
    private Date fechamedalla;

    @Column(name = "puestoDeportista", columnDefinition="CHAR(1)")
    private String puestodeportista;

    public Medallas() {

    }
```

---

and finally I have created a method in which I am trying to **delete** in **cascade**, passing it an object of **athletes** type and deleting all the associated **medals**.

---

### Delete Method

```
public static void Delete() {

        sesion.beginTransaction();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ID of the athletes to delete");
        int id = sc.nextInt();

        Deportistas myObject = (Deportistas) sesion.load(Deportistas.class, id);
        sesion.delete(myObject);

        sesion.flush();

        sesion.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

---

im getting a constraint violation:Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails,is there  a way too delete all the objects asociated to the class athlete?

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should add `orphanRemoval=true` to the `one-to-many` annotation. It means that dependent entities will be removed when the relationship to their "parent" entity will be destroyed.

I think then you need to change `session.delete()` method to `entityManager.remove()`.